# Assembly! inserir caracteres e imprimir o inverso

Tags: assembly, .net-assembly

olá sou um iniciante em Assembly.
Preciso de fazer um programa que recebe dois caracteres e imprime o inverso.

**Exemplo:**

Recebe: A  B

Visualiza:B  A

Alguem pode me ajudar

Comment: Sim, qual é a dúvida? Com base naquilo que você já sabe de Assembly, o que você tentou fazer? O que não conseguiu fazer? Da maneira que está, basicamente você colocou apenas o enunciado e dá a entender que deseja que façamos para você, o que justifica estar recebendo os votos negativos. Como é novo no site, recomendo que faça o [tour] para aprender o básico do site e leia o guia de [ask] - atente-se ao "*Você procurou exaustivamente por uma resposta antes de formular a pergunta?*".

Answer (score -2):

```
MOV AH, 01h
INT 21h
MOV BL, AL
INT 21h

MOV AH, 02h
MOV DL,AL
INT 21H
MOV DL,BL
MOV AH,2h
INT 21h
```